# Can't hide Boostrap button with css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When my page is loading, i would like to have a hidden button with css class.

It works with:

```
style="display: none"
```

but not with a css class:

```
<button class="ui left floated tiny button hidden">onclick="updateInformations()">Cancel</button>
```

and

```
.hidden { display:none }
```

It seems to have a conflit ".ui.button" in css.

How can i dow ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.hidden { display:none !important }
```

`!important` will make your class override bootstrap class's display behavior

Comment: In addition to @Pawan's answer, the order in which you're loading your stylesheets could be effecting which classes are being applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with styles, i would recommend you to read about '!important' rule and use this inside the .hidden like so:

```
.hidden { display: nony !important; }
```

This should replace the old display rule with the new one.

You can always use JS for setting up the page :

```
$('#MeButton .button').css('display': 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bootstrap classes for hiding elements:

```
class="hidden-xs "
```

Or use `hidden-sm / hidden-md / hidden-lg` according to your needs.